How do enable tagging in a `\list` based environment in `expl3`?
I have a list environment mylist created using expl3 with key=val support for parameter handling. The environment works fine, but, when using \DocumentMetadata it fails returning the error:
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.203   \item U
             sing mylist first item here, text text text text text text text

This is the smallest version I could create (it's part of a larger project), so I've put the least amount of keys possible since I don't understand tagging very well so I don't know if any of these are the ones that are affecting it.
The environment doesn't have keys to set \leftmargin or \itemindent, instead the keys list-offset and list-indent are used, the redefinition of \makelabel is necessary because of the keys font, align and wrap-label.
The not MWE file is the following (I just passed a list environment like LaTeX2e to expl3):
% \DocumentMetadata{ lang=en-US, pdfversion=2.0, pdfstandard=ua-2, testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}, uncompress }
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy list environment
\cs_new_eq:NN \__mylist_start_list:nn \list
\cs_new_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_list: \endlist
% Some vars
\int_new:N \l_mylist_level_int
\tl_new:N  \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
\box_new:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box
\dim_new:N \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
% Counters
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_counters:n #1
  {
    \tl_new:c  { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } { mycounx#1 }
    \newcounter{ mycounx#1 }
  }
\clist_map_inline:nn { i, ii, iii, iv } { \__mylist_counters:n {#1} }
% Width
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn #1#2
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_mylist_label_width_by_box {#2}
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box }
  }
% Register counters and default labelwidth
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_const:cn { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _tl } {#2}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl {#1}
  }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \arabic { 0 }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Alph { M }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \alph { m }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Roman { VIII }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \roman { viii }
% Style for label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_clear_new:N #1
    \tl_put_right:Ne #1 { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} }
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_widest_label_tl #1
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
      {
        \tl_replace_all:Nne #1 { ##1* } { \exp_not:N ##1 {#2} }
        \tl_greplace_all:Nne \g_mylist_widest_label_tl { ##1* }
           { \tl_use:c { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N ##1 _tl } }
      }
     \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
       { \tl_use:N \g_mylist_widest_label_tl }
     \tl_set_eq:cN { the #2 } #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn { cvn }
% Keys and vars for levels
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim  }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim      }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_#1_tl            }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl }
    \keys_define:nn { mylist / level-#1 }
      {
        font           .tl_set:c  = { l_mylist_label_font_style_#1_tl },
        labelsep       .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .initial:n = {0.3333em},
        labelwidth     .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim },
        label          .code:n    = {
                                      \__mylist_label_style:cvn { l_mylist_label_#1_tl }
                                        { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } {##1}
                                      \dim_set_eq:cN
                                        { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
                                    },
        label          .initial:n = {#2},
        wrap-label     .cs_set_protected:cp = { __mylist_wrapper_label_#1:n } ##1,
        wrap-label     .initial:n = {##1},
        align .choice:,
        align / left   .code:n    = \tl_clear:c { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl }
                                    \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } { \hfill },
        align / right  .code:n    = \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  } { \hfill }
                                    \tl_clear:c { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } ,
        align / center .code:n    = \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  } { \hfill }
                                    \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } { \hfill },
        align          .initial:n = {left},
        list-offset    .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim },
        list-indent    .code:n    = {
                                      \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
                                      \dim_set:cn { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim } {##1}
                                    },
        topsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_topsep_#1_skip },
        topsep        .initial:n  = {#3},
        partopsep     .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_partopsep_#1_skip },
        partopsep     .initial:n  = {#4},
        parsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_parsep_#1_skip },
        parsep        .initial:n  = {#5},
        itemsep       .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip },
        itemsep       .initial:n  = {#6},
        rightmargin   .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_rightmargin_#1_dim },
        listparindent .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_listparindent_#1_dim },
      }
  }
% Set keys and vars
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { i } { \arabic*.} { 8.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { ii } { (\alph*) } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { iii } { \roman*. } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }{ 0pt }{ 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { iv } { \Alph*.  } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }{ 0pt }{ 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
% Calc \itemindent and \leftmargin
% #1: \l_mylist_labelwidth_i_dim      #2: \l_mylist_labelsep_i_dim     #3: \l_mylist_listoffset_i_dim
% #4: \l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_i_dim  #5: \l_mylist_leftmargin_i_dim   #6: \l_mylist_itemindent_i_dim
% #7: \l_mylist_custom_margin_i_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nF #7 { \dim_set:Nn #4 { #1 + #2} }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {#4} < { 0pt }
       {
         \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4}
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
       }
       {
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} = {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { 0pt} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} < {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} > {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { -#1 - #2 + #4}  \dim_set:Nn #6 { #6*-1} }
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN { ccccccc }
% Second argument of list
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mylist_make_second_arg:n #1
  {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { __mylist_arg_two_#1: }
      {
        \__mylist_calc_hspace:ccccccc
          { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim } { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim } { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \clist_map_inline:nn
          { labelsep, labelwidth, itemindent, leftmargin, rightmargin, listparindent }
          { \dim_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_dim } }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { topsep, parsep, partopsep, itemsep }
          { \skip_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_skip } }
        \usecounter { mycounx#1 }
        \__mylist_make_label:
      }
  }
\clist_map_inline:nn { i, ii, iii, iv } { \__mylist_make_second_arg:n {#1} }
% Function for current level
\cs_new:Nn \__mylist_level:
  {
    \int_to_roman:n { \l_mylist_level_int }
  }
% \makelabel
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_make_label:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand \makelabel { m }
      {
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_fill_left_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_font_style_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
        \use:c { __mylist_wrapper_label_ \__mylist_level: :n } { ##1 }
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_fill_right_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
      }
  }
% Print label by level
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_print_label:
  {
    \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
  }
% key =val
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { en }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_parse_keys:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}
      {
        \keys_set:en { mylist / level-\__mylist_level: } {#1}
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylist}{ O{} }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_level_int
    \__mylist_parse_keys:n {#1}
    \__mylist_start_list:nn
      { \__mylist_print_label: }
      {
        \use:c { __mylist_arg_two_ \__mylist_level: : }
      }
  }
  { \__mylist_stop_list: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Some

\begin{mylist}[list-indent=1cm]
  \item Using mylist first item here, text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

  \item Using mylist second item here.
  \item Using mylist environment nested here:
  \begin{mylist}[list-offset=2cm]
    \item value second level, text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
    \item value second level
    \item value second level
      \begin{mylist}[list-offset=-2cm]
        \item value third level
        \item value third level
        \item value third level
      \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

End
\end{document}

What do I need to change to make it work (conditionally) with tagging?
I really don't know what the correct order is or what documentation I should read to understand how tagging works (and I don't know if there is a tutorial for beginners)
NOTE: In the real file I redefined \item and added multicol support, but I think this might give me an idea of ​​how to narrow down the example and make my own attempt to make it work.

Use \list then the tagging code knows where to patch. Or equivalently delay copying \list and \endlist until after the tagging code redefines them (at \begin{document})
 \DocumentMetadata{ lang=en-US, pdfversion=2.0, pdfstandard=ua-2, testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}, uncompress }
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy list environment
\cs_new_eq:NN \__mylist_start_list:nn \list
\cs_new_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_list: \endlist
% Some vars
\int_new:N \l_mylist_level_int
\tl_new:N  \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
\box_new:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box
\dim_new:N \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
% Counters
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_counters:n #1
  {
    \tl_new:c  { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } { mycounx#1 }
    \newcounter{ mycounx#1 }
  }
\clist_map_inline:nn { i, ii, iii, iv } { \__mylist_counters:n {#1} }
% Width
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn #1#2
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_mylist_label_width_by_box {#2}
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box }
  }
% Register counters and default labelwidth
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_const:cn { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _tl } {#2}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl {#1}
  }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \arabic { 0 }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Alph { M }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \alph { m }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Roman { VIII }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \roman { viii }
% Style for label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_clear_new:N #1
    \tl_put_right:Ne #1 { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} }
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_widest_label_tl #1
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
      {
        \tl_replace_all:Nne #1 { ##1* } { \exp_not:N ##1 {#2} }
        \tl_greplace_all:Nne \g_mylist_widest_label_tl { ##1* }
           { \tl_use:c { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N ##1 _tl } }
      }
     \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
       { \tl_use:N \g_mylist_widest_label_tl }
     \tl_set_eq:cN { the #2 } #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn { cvn }
% Keys and vars for levels
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim  }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim      }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_#1_tl            }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl }
    \keys_define:nn { mylist / level-#1 }
      {
        font           .tl_set:c  = { l_mylist_label_font_style_#1_tl },
        labelsep       .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .initial:n = {0.3333em},
        labelwidth     .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim },
        label          .code:n    = {
                                      \__mylist_label_style:cvn { l_mylist_label_#1_tl }
                                        { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } {##1}
                                      \dim_set_eq:cN
                                        { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
                                    },
        label          .initial:n = {#2},
        wrap-label     .cs_set_protected:cp = { __mylist_wrapper_label_#1:n } ##1,
        wrap-label     .initial:n = {##1},
        align .choice:,
        align / left   .code:n    = \tl_clear:c { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl }
                                    \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } { \hfill },
        align / right  .code:n    = \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  } { \hfill }
                                    \tl_clear:c { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } ,
        align / center .code:n    = \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_left_#1_tl  } { \hfill }
                                    \tl_set:cn  { l_mylist_label_fill_right_#1_tl } { \hfill },
        align          .initial:n = {left},
        list-offset    .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim },
        list-indent    .code:n    = {
                                      \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
                                      \dim_set:cn { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim } {##1}
                                    },
        topsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_topsep_#1_skip },
        topsep        .initial:n  = {#3},
        partopsep     .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_partopsep_#1_skip },
        partopsep     .initial:n  = {#4},
        parsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_parsep_#1_skip },
        parsep        .initial:n  = {#5},
        itemsep       .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip },
        itemsep       .initial:n  = {#6},
        rightmargin   .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_rightmargin_#1_dim },
        listparindent .dim_set:c = { l_mylist_listparindent_#1_dim },
      }
  }
% Set keys and vars
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { i } { \arabic*.} { 8.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { ii } { (\alph*) } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { iii } { \roman*. } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }{ 0pt }{ 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { iv } { \Alph*.  } { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
  { 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }{ 0pt }{ 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt }
% Calc \itemindent and \leftmargin
% #1: \l_mylist_labelwidth_i_dim      #2: \l_mylist_labelsep_i_dim     #3: \l_mylist_listoffset_i_dim
% #4: \l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_i_dim  #5: \l_mylist_leftmargin_i_dim   #6: \l_mylist_itemindent_i_dim
% #7: \l_mylist_custom_margin_i_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nF #7 { \dim_set:Nn #4 { #1 + #2} }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {#4} < { 0pt }
       {
         \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4}
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
       }
       {
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} = {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { 0pt} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} < {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} > {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { -#1 - #2 + #4}  \dim_set:Nn #6 { #6*-1} }
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN { ccccccc }
% Second argument of list
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mylist_make_second_arg:n #1
  {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { __mylist_arg_two_#1: }
      {
        \__mylist_calc_hspace:ccccccc
          { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim } { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim } { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \clist_map_inline:nn
          { labelsep, labelwidth, itemindent, leftmargin, rightmargin, listparindent }
          { \dim_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_dim } }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { topsep, parsep, partopsep, itemsep }
          { \skip_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_skip } }
        \usecounter { mycounx#1 }
        \__mylist_make_label:
      }
  }
\clist_map_inline:nn { i, ii, iii, iv } { \__mylist_make_second_arg:n {#1} }
% Function for current level
\cs_new:Nn \__mylist_level:
  {
    \int_to_roman:n { \l_mylist_level_int }
  }
% \makelabel
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_make_label:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand \makelabel { m }
      {
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_fill_left_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_font_style_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
        \use:c { __mylist_wrapper_label_ \__mylist_level: :n } { ##1 }
        \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_fill_right_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
      }
  }
% Print label by level
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_print_label:
  {
    \tl_use:c { l_mylist_label_ \__mylist_level: _tl }
  }
% key =val
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { en }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_parse_keys:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}
      {
        \keys_set:en { mylist / level-\__mylist_level: } {#1}
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylist}{ O{} }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_level_int
    \__mylist_parse_keys:n {#1}
    \list
      { \__mylist_print_label: }
      {
        \use:c { __mylist_arg_two_ \__mylist_level: : }
      }
  }
  { \endlist }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Some

\begin{mylist}[list-indent=1cm]
  \item Using mylist first item here, text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

  \item Using mylist second item here.
  \item Using mylist environment nested here:
  \begin{mylist}[list-offset=2cm]
    \item value second level, text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
    \item value second level
    \item value second level
      \begin{mylist}[list-offset=-2cm]
        \item value third level
        \item value third level
        \item value third level
      \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

End
\end{document}

produces
Package tagpdf Info: Finalizing the tagging structure:
(tagpdf)             Writing out ~57 structure objects
(tagpdf)             with ~22 'MC' leaf nodes.
(tagpdf)             Be patient if there are lots of objects!

Package tagpdf Info: writing ParentTree
Package tagpdf Info: writing IDTree
Package tagpdf Info: writing RoleMap
Package tagpdf Info: writing ClassMap
Package tagpdf Info: writing NameSpaces
Package tagpdf Info: writing StructElems
Package tagpdf Info: writing Root
 )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/pdftex/pdftexspace.pfb>
Output written on aa802.pdf (1 page, 59543 bytes).
Transcript written on aa802.log.



Just curious, why does the tagging code wait until begindocument to redefine list?

@mbert because it wants to win over packages that redefine list too.

Ohh...I didn't even think that change would make a difference...Could you expand your answer to make the delayed copy only in case tagging code is active?

@PabloGonzálezL why not delay always? its anyway safer, but with tagging compare  the two definitions  shown by \show\list\begin{document}\show\list

@PabloGonzálezL Side remark: with the new list code most of your definition is probably unnecessary as the new lists already have an optional argument that takes a key-val list.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, \hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument} { mylist } { ... } It's what I was looking for :D

@UlrikeFischer In which of the documentations is that found?

@PabloGonzálezL texdoc latex-lab-block
